# How can you delete Steam server browser history?

Tags: steam

So I want to delete my Steam game server browser history, because there's old servers that keep coming back, and Malwarebytes keeps blocking outbound IPs when I open the server browser on the history tab. There are game servers hosted on blacklisted IPs, so I want to delete them to stop the notifications. I am absolutely certain the server history is related to the steam cloud because:

1. I have deleted all steam files and redownloaded it
2. I have tried right clicking history results to remove, but steam recreates the same serverbrowser_hist.vdf files.

The Steam AppID for the browser is "7".

Is there a way I can totally wipe the Steam cloud and reset everything INCLUDING steam server browser history?

Comment: This might help: http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2470784 (You should make it into an answer if it does)

Comment: That kind of helped. I was able to edit the text and then enable cloud, and steam used that empty file then. I think its similar to the powershell tutorial, both will help. I did it the notepad way ( notepad because it was only vdf files I wanted to change that were on the cloud. ) I did this on another pc, and it also got the 27kb browser history file with the servers list that caused ip warnings (one server inside the vdf file was part of a blacklisted ip range, its harmless for steam to ping it, but id rather it not.) So this wasnt an isolated incident, and now my steam is fine.

Comment: @Keyes You should add this as an answer and mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the file and enable Steam Cloud. Steam will then use that empty file.

I think its similar to the powershell method from [this post](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2470784):

```
Clear-Content C:\<Path to Steam>\userdata\SteamID\<AppID>\remote\<offending file>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able trick Steam into uploading a clean copy of the file if you edit/clear it rather than just deleting it.

However, you could as well use the more or less official way:

- Open the server browser.
- Click the first entry in the list.
- Scroll all the way down and shift-click the last entry.
- This should highlight all entries.
- Right click any entry and there should be a context menu entry to remove the entry (which will then apply to everything being selected).

Comment: I do this, but mbam still gives warnings.I will try to edit it later. The more or less official way doesnt seem to work. If I reinstal steam, it seems to delete it, however after a while it comes back.

Comment: I turned off cloud, opened serverbrowser_hist.vdf with notepad and deleted the text. Restarted steam, turned on cloud, closed steam, deleted the serverbrowser_hist.vdf (I did this to see if cloud would redownload the old one or my new blank one)
Opened steam, it "updated configuration". I guess it was retrieving the lost .vdf file. It has downloaded, and it is the 0kb one (all text gone) rather than the 27kb one with the servers I found it was indeed the cloud holding the serverbrowser_hist.vdf because I logged into another PC and it downloaded the 27kb vdf. Now mbams warnings stopped.